# Эмуляция команды ROR

Tags: c#

Приветствую всех :)
Собственно интересует такой вопрос: Как можно имитировать ассемблеровскую команду ROR в C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
static UInt32 ROL(UInt32 number, int shift)
{
    shift %= 31;
    return ((number << shift) | (number >> (32 - shift)));
}

static UInt32 ROR(UInt32 number, int shift)
{
    shift %= 31;
    return ((number >> shift) | (number << (32 - shift)));
}
```

Comment: Благодарю :)

Answer (score 2):

C:

```
#define WORD_LENGTH (8*sizeof(value))

int 
rol(unsigned value, int places)
{
  return (value<<places)|(value>>(WORD_LENGTH-places));
}

int 
ror(unsigned int value, int places)
{
  return (value>>places)|(value<<WORD_LENGTH-places);
}
```